# column comparing within 2 CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 CSV files that have 3 columns called ‘num,’date’ and ‘tex.

File1

```
num         date                tex   

20170512    12/05/2017 15:39    1001  

20170512    12/05/2017 15:39    1001 

20170908    08/09/2017 02:42    1001  

20170908    08/09/2017 06:30    1001
```

File 2

```
num              date                tex   

201705332212    12/05/2017 15:39    1001  

20170523212     12/05/2017 15:39    100156 

2017232320908   08/09/2017 02:42    10012  

20170908        08/09/2017 06:30    1001
```

desired output

diff.csv

```
num              date                tex   

201705332212    12/05/2017 15:39    1001  

20170523212     12/05/2017 15:39    100156 

2017232320908   08/09/2017 02:42    10012
```

I want to match both columns ‘num’ and ‘tex’. currently the below code is just checks difference in the whole file and not against column 'num' and 'tex'. Ideally, i want if both columns ‘num’ and ‘tex’ is different I would like it to write it to the out.csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `csv` module.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open("file1.csv","rU") as file_0, open("file2.csv","rU") as file_1, open("out.csv", "w") as out_file:
    file_0 = csv.reader(file_0, delimiter=";")
    file_1 = csv.reader(file_1, delimiter=";")
    next(file_0)                                                   #Skip Header

    out_file_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=";")
    out_file_writer.writerow(next(file_1))                         #Writer Header

    for k, v in zip(file_0, file_1):
        if (k[0] != v[0]) or (k[-1] != v[-1]):
            out_file_writer.writerow(v)                            #Writer Diff
```

Comment: Yes, `(k[0] != v[0]) ` ==> `num`   & `(k[-1] != v[-1])` ==> `tex`...You can test by printing k[0], v[0] and k[-1], v[-1]

Comment: `open("out.csv", "wb") as out_file:` ?

Comment: i used your code of 'open("out.csv", "wb") as out_file: and got the following error  out_file_writer.writerow(next(file_1))                         #Writer Header
peError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: python3 use --> `open("out.csv", "w", newline='') as out_file:`

Comment: Looks like some of the columns are empty...check for emptiness first ...

Comment: Check the delimiter...I have used `delimiter=";"` as an example in the above solution.